# How do I display User Guides from my Help menu in my SwiftUI Mac app?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I have coded a SwiftUI app and posted it on the Mac App Store. I have also written a detailed User Guide and various technical guides to help users understand how to use the app and interpret its display.  All of these .md files are included in my app.  How do I allow the Help menu to open and display these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how other people do this, but this is the approach I would use:

```
import SwiftUI


@main
struct MacApp: App {
    @State var showHelp = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showHelp) { HelpView() }
        }.commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: .help) {
                Button(action: {showHelp = true}) {
                    Text("App Help")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For ios:

```
@main
struct IOSApp: App {
    @State var showHelp = false

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(showHelp: $showHelp)
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showHelp) { HelpView() }
        }
    }
}
```

Pass `showHelp` around (or as a `ObservableObject/EnvironmentObject`),
then set `showHelp=true`, when clicking on a Button with `Image(systemName: "info.circle")`
for example.

```
struct HelpView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State var mdText = AttributedString()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            Button(action: {dismiss()}) {
                Text("Done").foregroundColor(.blue)
            }.padding(10)
            ScrollView {
                Text("Welcome to my app help")
                Text(mdText)
            }.frame(width: 333, height: 333)
        }
        .onAppear {
            // get your .md files contents
            do {
                mdText = try AttributedString(markdown: "***help file contents***")
            } catch {
                // error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT1: reading `md` file that is included in your App.

```
    .onAppear {
        var str: String = ""
        if let mdFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "README", ofType: "md") {
            do {
                str = try String(contentsOfFile: mdFile)
                mdText = try AttributedString(markdown: str)
            } catch {
                // deal with error
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT2: ContentView for ios app:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var showHelp: Bool  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {showHelp = true}) {
          VStack {
            Image(systemName: "info.circle").resizable().frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            Text("Info").font(.caption)
          }.foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  It works perfectly.  I need help with one detail: In your line ```try AttributedString(markdown: "***help file contents***")```, how do I insert the file path to my document - such as ```filepath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "README", withExtension: "md")``` ?

Comment: updated my answer with reading from your `README.md` file.

Comment: Thank you again for your help.  I'm actually developing a multiplatform app.  Your solution works fine for macOS, but Xcode complains that ContentView "is passing to a call that takes no arguments" for iOS.  What would my ContentView look like for iOS?  What should an iPhone user do to view the md file?

Comment: updated my answer for the ios ContentView.

Answer (score 1):

This was really helpful for me. When I used this code I noticed that the `Markdown` capabilities of `AttributedString` are really limited.

Some further digging showed that the `Text` view actually supports `Markdown` out of the box, much better than `AttributedString`.

So I ended up with the following code which has better support for `MarkDown`:

```swift
struct HelpView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State var mdText = String()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            Button(action: {dismiss()}) {
                Text("Done").foregroundColor(.blue)
            }.padding(10)
            ScrollView {
                Text("Welcome to my app help")
                Text(mdText)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 500, minHeight: 700)
        }
        .onAppear {
            if let mdFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "README", ofType: "md") {
                do {
                    mdText = try String(contentsOfFile: mdFile)
                } catch {
                    // deal with error
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```